# Rails multiple record form returns: undefined method `model_name' for Array:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a form to edit several records at once.

The records of the Mapping class are children of the records of the MappingsList class:

```
class Mapping < ActiveRecord::Base
...
    belongs_to :mappings_list
```

.

```
class MappingsList < ActiveRecord::Base
...
    has_many :mappings
```

In order to select the set of records to edit, from the mappings_list show view, I pass the mappings_list_id to the mappings controller:

```
class MappingsController < ApplicationController
...
# GET /mappings/1/edit
def edit
  @mappings_list = MappingsList.find(params[:id])
  @mappings_batch = Array(@mappings_list.mappings.each)
end
```

But when calling the form:

```
<%= form_for [@mappings_list, @mappings_batch] do |f| %>

<--! Loop with details mappings data to update -->

      <% @mappings_batch.each do |map| %>
        <% fields_for map do m %>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="span2 field"> <%= m.text_field :source_code, :disabled => true %>
            </div>
            <div class="span2 field"> <%= m.text_field :source_caption, :disabled => true %>
            </div>   
            <div class="span2 field"> <%= m.collection_select :target_caption, @target_values, :value_caption, :value_caption %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr/>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I get the error message:

```
Showing ...MyApp/app/views/mappings/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for Array:Class
```

Which I don't understand.

Can someone give me some hints about how to solve this ?

Thanks a lot,

Best regards,

Frédéric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why [@mappings_list, @mappings_batch] ?  It's wrong! Also you have a lot of other mistakes.

The right solution is:

```
<%= form_for @mappings_list do |f| %>

    <%= f.fields_for :mappings do |m| %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span2 field"> <%= m.text_field :source_code, :disabled => true %>
        </div>
        <div class="span2 field"> <%= m.text_field :source_caption, :disabled => true %>
        </div>   
        <div class="span2 field"> <%= m.collection_select :target_caption, @target_values, :value_caption, :value_caption %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr/>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And don't forget:

```
class MappingsList < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :mappings
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Chumakof ! Being new at RoR, I mainly know Hartl's tutorial, and my first approach was to build parent-child relationship with separated objects, views and controllers. Your solution is smart and efficient. Thank you for the demonstration ! cpaciba bolschoï ;-)